# How can I apply a namedtuple onto a function?

Tags: python, function, call, namedtuple

In Python, if you have a dictionary

```
d = {'foo': 1, 'bar': False}
```

You can apply this onto a function that accept `foo` and `bar` keyword arguments by

```
def func(foo, bar):
    # Do something complicated here
    pass

func(**d)
```

But if instead, I wanted to call `func` with the namedtuple defined below:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Record = namedtuple('Record', 'foo bar')
r = Record(foo=1, bar=False)
func(r)   # !!! this will not work
```

What's the syntax for this?

Comment: Did you mean `func(*r)` in the last code block?

Comment: Have you tried using `func(*d)`? That is, trying to use it as a varargs and not a dict?

Comment: mr2ert, write that as an answer and I will accept it. A small experiment shows that they do indeed match by keyword.

Comment: @fatuhoku It's okay. The other answers cover this pretty thoroughly already, so just accept one of them.  Thanks though! :)

Comment: Okay, my previous comment was incorrect. Application of namedtuple fields is positional, as the marked answer suggests. My 'experiment' was flawed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A namedtuple instance has a [`._asdict()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict):

```
func(**r._asdict())
```

but if the namedtuple attributes are in the same order as the arguments of the function, you could just apply it as a sequence instead:

```
func(*r)
```

Here the two values of the namedtuple are applied, in order, to the keyword arguments in the function. Those two arguments can be addressed as positional arguments still, after all!

For your sample function, both work:

```
>>> def func(foo, bar):
...     print foo, bar
... 
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Record = namedtuple('Record', 'foo bar')
>>> r = Record(foo=1, bar=False)
>>> func(**r._asdict())
1 False
>>> func(*r)
1 False
```

Comment: You might want to include number of arguments should also be the same.

Comment: @thefourtheye: that goes for the dictionary-applied-as-keyword-args case too; that's not special to namedtuples.